# How to test writing to the queue without actually writing to the queue

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, message-queue

I am sure this is probably a simple question but I am new to programming and I am having a tough time understanding mocks. I am wondering if its possible in python to test a function that writes to the queue without actually writing to the queue.

```
def write_to_queue():
   
   #call queue client
   #do some status checking
   return status

def post() :
     #do something 
     return write_to_queue()
```

Is there a way to test write_to_queue without actually writing to the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Mocking usually works like this:

1. Make sure the object to mock is injected into the tested code and not just created there.
2. Inject the mock instead of the real thing in a test scenario.
3. Assert on the expected behavior by verifying that the expected method calls where executed.